# How to append span within another span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ctLc610/4/)
Basically I want to append a span element within the span with id 'spanValidation'. And also I want to add and remove some classes in some elements.Previously it was done using Custom Model validation in MVC and JQuery,but now I want to handle it in JQuery.
This is my HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <label class="control-label text-primary" for="SSN">Social Security Number</label><span> </span><span class="help-inline">(Last Four Digits Only)</span>
        <input name="SSN" class="form-control" id="SSN" type="text" value="" data-val-length-max="4" data-val-length="Enter only the last four digits of the SSN." data-val="true" data-val-regex-pattern="^\d{4}$" data-val-regex="Enter only the last four digits of the SSN.">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <br class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" id="spanValidation" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="SSN"></span>


      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

This is my JS:

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function (event) {
 alert("hi");
 if ( $("#SSN").val() === "" ) {
    $(".spanValidation").addClass("field-validation-error").removeClass("field-validation-valid");
    $(".spanValidation").append("<span >Enter at least one of the following: Account Number, SSN, or Birth Date.</span>");
  }
  else {
    $(".spanValidation").removeClass("field-validation-error").addClass("field-validation-valid");
    $('span[id^="errorSpan"]').remove();
  }
 }
```

The problem is, even though the code is getting executed, but ut is not adding the new span with id 'errorSpan' and also it is not updating the classes associated with the elements.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: and? what is the problem?

Comment: Your HTML has "spanValidation" as the element id, but you're referencing it with jQuery as ".spanValidation" - the `.` is for class references, so you want `"#spanValidation"`

Comment: @Pointy,Sorry,that was a copy-paste error,in actual code it's not there.. even after changing, it's still not adding the span.

Comment: Is the condition `$("#SSN").val() === ""` true while the script is execute?

Comment: A "copy-paste" error? Your copy-paste process somehow changed `$("#spanValidation")` to `$(".spanValidation")`?

Comment: Any reason you are not using HTML5 pattern attribute and CSS3 :valid and :invalid pseudo-classes. These would do what you are attempting with  the only JavaScript needed being to set the customValidation error message.

Comment: @empiric, yes, it is executing when that condition is true, but not adding the span.

Comment: @Pointy:What I mean is the error was there initially, then I had rectified,but copied the older version.

Comment: @user2948533 [here is a fixed version of your fiddle, which had syntax errors.](https://jsfiddle.net/txag0dbh/)

Comment: @pointy,thank you.But please understand ,I need to add the new span with id='errorSpan',because I need to remove it also if the else condition satisfies.

Comment: So add the id in the markup? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I mean the new span which we are introducing, we may need to undo it,if user has entered something inside the SSN text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to include jQuery and add a closing `)` and bear in mind that `id` selectors are referenced by a `#` and not by a `.` as noted in the comments:

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function (event) {
  alert("hi");
  if ( $("#SSN").val() === "" ) {
    $("#spanValidation").addClass("field-validation-error").removeClass("field-validation-valid");
    $("#spanValidation").append("<span >Enter at least one of the following: Account Number, SSN, or Birth Date.</span>");
  }
  else {
    $("#spanValidation").removeClass("field-validation-error").addClass("field-validation-valid");
    $('span[id^="errorSpan"]').remove();
  }
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/2ctLc610/7/)

If you inspect the HTML you'll see that the `span` does get appended.

**UPDATE**

To remove the span use:

```
$('#spanValidation').empty();
```

Instead of `$('span[id^="errorSpan"]').remove()`. The new span does not have an id and, unless there's any content you'd want to retain in the parent span, you should not worry about assigning a selector as `.empty()` removes all content.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/2ctLc610/9/)

Comment: Thanks Peter,But if you remove the id of the newly added span, how can I remove it when SSN text box is not null(I mean the else part)

Comment: I see what you mean. `$('span[id^="errorSpan"]').remove();` should be `$('#spanValidation').empty();`. Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/2ctLc610/9/

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this: spanValidation is id while you are using it like a class

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function (event) {
alert("hi");


if ( $("#SSN").val() === "" ) {
    $("#spanValidation").addClass("field-validation-error").removeClass("field-validation-valid");
    $("#spanValidation").append("<span >Enter at least one of the following: Account Number, SSN, or Birth Date.</span>");
  }
  else {
    $("#spanValidation").removeClass("field-validation-error").addClass("field-validation-valid");
    $('span[id^="errorSpan"]').remove();
  }
 }
```

Comment: thank you, but please go through the comments section above!

Comment: @user2948533 people shouldn't have to read all the comments. Fix the question when it is inaccurate. If someone provides you an answer explain why it doesn't suit your needs